# urllib downloads a different file than what I do manually

Tags: python, url, urllib2, urllib

I'm attempting to download the result from a flight search but I keep getting a file that differs from the one I can obtain by right-clicking and storing the site manually. I've tried `urllib` , `urllib2` and every command I could find here to no avail.

Here's a MWE:

```
import urllib2
import urllib

url = "https://ar.aeromexico.com/search/flight/RoundTrip/EZE/MEX/2014-12-10/2015-01-25/1/0/0?"

# Get data.
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)

# Write to file.
s = f.read()
f.close()
ff = open("temp.del", "w")
ff.write(s)
ff.close()
```

Other attempts:

```
# 1
f = urllib.urlopen(url)

# 2
req = urllib2.Request(url)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)

# 3
urllib.urlretrieve(url, "temp.del")
```

If I compare the file I obtain with any of the above commands, it's different from the one I get downloading it with a right-click and "Save as".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How different are they? There are lots of possibilities, including the web server checking which User-Agent you are and sending back different data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there is so much more happening to load and render the page on the browser side. There can be [asynchronous requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) being made to load the additional data, javascript code being executed etc `urllib`/`urllib2` gets you only the initial HTML page that browser receives in the first place.

Besides, as @tdelaney noted, there can be additional checks applied by the server, like checking your `User-Agent`, or some custom headers, or cookies etc.

There are typically two general ways to proceed in this case:

- research what is responsible for requesting and showing the desired data on the page and simulate these requests/logic in your code. There are tons of libraries that might be applicable in your case:

  - [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) (typically in conjunction with [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/))
  - [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)
  - [mechanicalsoup](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup)
  - [robobrowser](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser)
- utilize a real browser, let it construct the page and then retrieve the data you need from the HTML. This is where [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) package would help.

For example, here is how you can get the total prices for every result using `selenium` + `Firefox` web driver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://ar.aeromexico.com/search/flight/RoundTrip/EZE/MEX/2014-12-10/2015-01-25/1/0/0?")

results = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'results')))
for price in results.find_elements_by_class_name('total-price'):
    print price.text.strip()

driver.close()
```

Prints `U$S 2.147`.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely an AJAX app. `curl`ing it and taking a quick glance, it looks like there's a form and a bunch of hidden divs, but everything else is generating dynamically with jQuery and Bootstrap. So `selenium` is probably the way to go here.

Comment: @abarnert totally agree, taking the "high-level" approach here looks much easier. Thanks.

Comment: @abarnert looks like ur upvote got me to the legendary :) I guess I will be drinking tonight

Comment: Well, have another upvote, which means you have to have another drink. :)